# Weird error with JAXB when unmarshalling two XML strings, one succeeds and the other fails with JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, jaxb

I'm working on a project built with Spring Boot (v.2.7.5) with Java 17 that has to handle XML's. It's generating sources from a whole bunch of XSD-files and uploads XML's to a third party using an API. It has to handle both marshalling and unmarshaling of XML with namespaces etc. That isn't an issue though.

There is a part of the application where a file is fetched from disk, unmarshalled to a Java object, which is of one of the generated classes types, then some information is added to the object using one of it's setters and then the xml content is uploaded to a third party using an API.

The problem is that when the application has two files to unmarshall almost simultaneously (they are handled as separate scheduled jobs by Spring Boot so they are not handled within the same function or anything like that) one of them succeeds and the other (second one in order being processed) throws the exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:230)
```

This is super weird! How can it succeed even once if a JAXB-API implementation isn't on the classpath?!

The application is built using Gradle and the build.gradle has among others the following contents:

```
dependencies {
    ....

    // JAXB
    implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    runtimeOnly "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.3"
}
```

So clearly an implementation of the JAXB-API is on the classpath!

I have tried all the various implementations, Glassfish, EclipseLink MOXy etc. various versions, all with the same issue.

What's even more weird is that when I run the application inside my IDE I don't get this error. I get it when the application is packaged into a Docker container (it's being run inside a Kubernetes cluster in production).

Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: weird! how  about this? https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch06.html#d0e6879

Comment: I've thought about the thread safety and have changed so that the method doing the unmarshalling is not static and that a new unmarshaller is created inside it each time like so:
```JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyType.class); Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();```
But I still have the same issue.

Comment: Turns out it was probably the thread safety. It works now. I also updated to version 2.3.7 (latest 2.3.x for the time being) and it works now. I followed the example provided in the link of having the marshalling and unmarshalling in a non-static method and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be that marshallers and unmarshallers aren't thread safe with JAXB as described here: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch06.html#d0e6879

I also updated to version 2.3.7 of the jaxb-impl, which probably had no real impact on the problem being resolved but I wanted to throw it out there just in case.

The solution was to create a new unmarshaller each time and have it done inside a non-static method.

Edit:
The solution above didn't fully work but making the methods that were doing the marshalling/unmarshalling synchronized did resolve the issue completely.